# Returning a dictionary of numbers from a function in python

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

I want to return a dictionary of elements by assigning each value of a list to "like" but I keep coming up with an error. This is my code.

```
def f([a,b,c]):
    d={a:'like'}
    for x in [a,b,c]:
        d[x]='like'
    return d
```

Comment: "An error" - want to be more specific?

Comment: I think I might know the problem, is there any way to convert a list to a tuple?

Comment: Your code has multiple errors, both syntax errors and logical errors.  What particular error message to you get?

Comment: The error is "invalid syntax"

Comment: Converting your list to a tuple won't help in any way.

Comment: what are the syntax and logical errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that this is what you want to do:

```
def f(my_list):
    return dict((x, "like") for x in my_list)
```

Example:

```
>>> f([1, 2, 3])
{1: 'like', 2: 'like', 3: 'like'}
```

In Python 2.7 or above, the function can also be written as

```
def f(my_list):
    return {x: "like" for x in my_list}
```

Regarding your original code: There is no such syntax as `def f([a, b, c])`.  I can only guess what this is supposed to mean, there are no square brackets in a parameter list.  If you want to pass in a list, use a single parameter.

In the updated version of the code the other errors were removed.  The initialization of `d` is still strange since it would be enough to use an empty dictionary:

```
d = {}
```

Answer (score 5):

`dict.fromkeys` is a convenience constructor for this:

```
>>> dict.fromkeys([1,2,3], 'like')
{1: 'like', 2: 'like', 3: 'like'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Above Python 2.7 you could do a dict comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3,]
>>> {i: 'like' for i in my_list}
{1: 'like', 2: 'like', 3: 'like'}
```

Edit: Looks like @SvenMarnach edited his comment as I was typing this up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but it's maybe something like this:

```
def f(lst):
    d = {}
    for x in lst:
        d[x] = 'like'
    return d
```

if it is you can either do that or better:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> dict((x, 'like') for x in lst)
{'a': 'like', 'b': 'like', 'c': 'like'}
```